# Datatables warning(table id = 'example')

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

Good morning,

I have a question about DataTables.

In a tutorial I found a table that I can edit "inline".
I would like to have the table in German.

The code for the table:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){

 var dataTable = $('#sample_data').DataTable({    
  "processing" : true,
  "serverSide" : true,
  "order" : [],
  "ajax" : {
   url:"fetch.php",
   type:"POST"
  }

 });

 $('#sample_data').on('draw.dt', function(){
  $('#sample_data').Tabledit({
   url:'action.php',
   dataType:'json',
   columns:{
    identifier : [0, 'id'],
    editable:[[1, 'nachname'], [2, 'vorname'], [3, 'datum', '{"1":"Male","2":"Female"}']]
   },
   restoreButton:false,
   onSuccess:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
   {
    if(data.action == 'delete')
    {
     $('#' + data.id).remove();
     $('#sample_data').DataTable().ajax.reload();
    }
   }
  });
 });


});
</script>
```

```html
HTML-Code:
<html>
 <head>
  <title>How to use Tabledit plugin with jQuery Datatable in PHP Ajax</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/assets/js/tabledit.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <h3 align="center">How to use Tabledit plugin with jQuery Datatable in PHP Ajax</h3>
   <br />
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Sample Data</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     <div class="table-responsive">
      <table id="sample_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
       <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>First Name</th>
         <th>Last Name</th>
         <th>Gender</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <br />
  <br />
 </body>
</html>
```

The code for the language setting German:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#sample_data').DataTable({
    lengthMenu: [[25, 50, 100, 150, 200, 300, 400, 500], [25, 50, 100, 150, 200, 300, 400, 500]],
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'copy',
            text: '<i class="fa fa-clone" aria-hidden="true"></i> Kopieren',
        },
        {
            extend: 'print',
            text: '<i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i> Drucken'
        },
        {
            extend: 'excel',
            text: '<i class="fa fa-table" aria-hidden="true"></i> Excel'
        },
        {
            extend: 'pdf',
            text: '<i class="far fa-file-pdf"></i> PDF'
        }
    ],
    language: {
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/German.json",
            searchPlaceholder: "Suchbegriff eingeben...",
        }    
    } );    
} );
```

Can anyone help me? Unfortunately I do not get any further. I get the error:

> DataTables warning: table id=sample_data - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

Answer (score 0):

If your facing error `Cannot reinitialise DataTable` then you should destroy before initialise DataTable like

```
var dataTable = undefined;
$(document).ready( function () {
    if(dataTable) dataTable.destroy();

    dataTable = $('#sample_data').DataTable({
    lengthMenu: [[25, 50, 100, 150, 200, 300, 400, 500], [25, 50, 100, 150, 200, 300, 400, 500]],
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'copy',
            text: '<i class="fa fa-clone" aria-hidden="true"></i> Kopieren',
        },
        {
            extend: 'print',
            text: '<i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i> Drucken'
        },
        {
            extend: 'excel',
            text: '<i class="fa fa-table" aria-hidden="true"></i> Excel'
        },
        {
            extend: 'pdf',
            text: '<i class="far fa-file-pdf"></i> PDF'
        }
    ],
    language: {
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/German.json",
            searchPlaceholder: "Suchbegriff eingeben...",
        }    
    } );    
} );
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I replaced my code with yours, but I also got the same error message. :(